# Updraft Plus (free) Backup to Localhost

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I cannot figure out how to clone my backup to a localhost
Since the backup consists of 4 separate folders.

The folders are below.[image]

I haven't use this plugin before so any help is appreciated.
When I go to localhost/mysite
The view looks like this..
[image]

So Im guessing I have to extract and merge these files into one.

I am using Xammp 7.3.12-0

Answer (score 0):

you will need to install the fresh Wordpress of the same version and then paste the backup folders in that Wordpress project.

and then import the database and then your current backup will run successfully

Comment: Okay, let me try it :)